# Modifying a member variable

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm having an issue with modifying a member of a class. I overloaded the operators and I think that I am calling the member correctly to modify it but am getting the issue that the "expression must be a modifiable l-value.
Any help would be appreciated
.h file

```
public:
    account& operator+= (float x);
    account& operator-= (float y);
    float set_balance();
```

.cpp file

```
   account& account::operator+=(float x)
    {
        this->acct_balance += x;
        return *this;
    }
    account& account::operator+=(float y)
    {
        this->acct_balance -= y;
        return *this;
    }
    float account::set_balance()
    {
        return this->acct_balance;
    }
```

main file

```
//deposit
        else if (imput == 2)
        {
            float deposit;
            cout << "Please enter the amount to deposit: ";
            cin >> deposit;
            user1.set_balance() += deposit;

        }
        //withdrawl
        else if (imput == 3)
        {
            float withdraw;
            cout << "Please enter the amount to deposit: ";
            cin >> withdraw;
            user1.set_balance() += withdraw; 

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `set_balance` function doesn't set anything. You probably want this:

```
float& account::get_balance()
{
    return this->acct_balance;
}
```

Then you can do `user1.get_balance() += withdraw;`.

This `get_balance` function gets the balance as a modifiable l-value, which is what you need.

Since you have an `operator+=`, you could also just do `user1 += withdraw;`.